# Referência a respostas no SO-pt em perguntas feitas no SO-en

Tags: suporte

É muitas das vezes, colocada em respostas de algumas perguntas feitas aqui (SO-pt) referências ou indicações de respostas no SO-en, o que é ótimo, dada a maturidade(tmepo de existência) e abrangência do idioma.

Porém, tenciono saber se o contrário é válido (acredito que é)? Ou se existe algum regulamento interno que proíbe redirecionar/referenciar respostas do SO-pt no SO-en?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ["Crossposting de respostas para crossposting de perguntas, como proceder?"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1072/215)

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi o objetivo da sua pergunta.

Se quer saber se pode usar as postagens existentes aqui como fonte em outras postagens em outros sites, entre eles o SOen, pode, desde que indique a fonte conforme a [indicação legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal) no site que usa a licença de conteúdo [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Mas se quer saber se o SOen aceita referência para o nosso site, você precisaria perguntar no [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) deles. São comunidades distintas, cada uma com suas regras. Mas posso lhe adiantar que provavelmente não seria bem aceito por alguns.

Pense bem, saber um mínimo de inglês é fundamental para qualquer programador. Então nós usarmos referências em inglês não é um problema. Mas programadores do mundo todo não são obrigados saberem português. Então suas referências na nossa língua postadas no SOen serão mais ou menos o que seria russo para nós. Não teria muita serventia. No mínimo seria ignorado, possivelmente você receberia negativos de alguns usuários. É improvável que a única fonte seja o SOpt.

Mas como está dito nos comentários abaixo, se a resposta não depender da referência no SOpt, se for apenas para dar o crédito, não seria muito problema.

Comment: Não acho que seja tão "sério". Se a resposta estiver bem explicada (em inglês) e o idioma do link estiver claramente sinalizado, tudo bem. Embora não seja tão comum, existem links para conteúdos em outros idiomas no SO.

Comment: Também acho que não vai ter grande problema, mas eu duvido que todos pensem assim, vide [discussão acalorada](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271998/fluent-in-spanish-were-hiring-a-community-manager-for-a-spanish-stack-overflow).

Comment: E se houver um bloco de código legal aqui no SOpt, então é esperanto e até um russo vai querer o copy/paste. Lembro de quando a gente só encontra um pedaço de código num blog chinês escondido na página 20 do google... salvação.